# Swift AnyObject as Dictionary get element that doesn't exist is not nil

Tags: ios, swift, casting, anyobject

I'm confronted to a problem with cast in Swift

Here the code :

```
 init(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject)
{
    super.init(entity:NSEntityDescription.entityForName("File", inManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext.currentContext())!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext.currentContext());

    var result : [String:AnyObject] = representation as! [String : AnyObject];
    if representation["result"] != nil {
        print("result = \(representation["result"])")
        result = representation["result"] as! [String : AnyObject]
    }
}
```

In some cases i expect that representation["result"] equal nil, in that cases when i print representation["result"] the debuger give me nil but I still pass the condition and display "result = nil" in the log and when it executes next line it crashes 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Which is normal because I try to unwrap a nil value!

But I did found that if I do:

```
var result : [String:AnyObject] = representation as! [String : AnyObject];
if result["result"] != nil {
    print("result = \(result["result"])")
    result = representation["result"] as! [String : AnyObject]
}
```

It works pretty well

I know, I know some of you will say: you found a solution why post on stackoverflow- 
I did because i want to understand why the first solution doesn't work, and because my error is certainly not specific to this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have to cast `representation["result"]` to a dictionary before you check it, so if you type `representation["result"] as! [String : AnyObject]` it should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not compile since `representation["result"]` results in

> error: ambiguous use of 'subscript'

Apart from that consider using `if let` instead:

```
if let res = result["result"] {
    print("result = \(res)")
    result = res as! [String : AnyObject]
}
```

Beyond that you should make your casts safer by using `guard`s:

```
guard let result = representation as? [String : AnyObject] else {
    // not a suitable dictionary
    return
}
if let res = result["result"] {
    guard let resultDic = res as? [String : AnyObject] else {
        // not a suitable dictionary neither
        return
    }
    print(resultDic)
}
```

Comment: Thx for the reply, my code is compiling, i don't know why it not compile on your side second, in real I used to do a : if let result = (representation["result"] ?? representation) as? [String:AnyObject] to check but for my explanation i wanted to be more general. The answer i was looking for is from Hussein Alzand where i needed to cast when i compare so in the end i do =   if let result = ((representation["result"] as? [String:AnyObject]) ?? representation) as? [String:AnyObject]

Comment: Sorry but it does compil! I didn't take your answer because Hussein explained that the cast has to be done on the comparison as well.